# Rearrange python pandas dataframe (partially transposing)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe (index(es) ignored):

| Account | Currency | Side | Quote1 | Broker1 | Quote2 | Broker2 | Quote3 | Broker3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acc1 | EUR/USD | BUY | 1.218 | Brk3 | 1.216 | Brk6 | NaN | NaN |
| Acc2 | GBP/USD | SELL | 1.345 | Brk6 | 1.330 | Brk5 | 1.341 | Brk3 |

python representation of dataframe:

```
data = {
"Account":["Acc1","Acc2"],"Currency":["EUR/USD","GBP/USD"],"Side":["BUY","SELL"],
"Quote1":[1.218,1.345],"Broker1":["Brk3","Brk6"],
"Quote2":[1.216,1.330],"Broker2":["Brk6","Brk5"],
"Quote3":[np.nan,1.341],"Broker3":[np.nan,"Brk3"]
}
```

I want to rearrange the above dataframe to obtain the following dataframe:

```
| Account | Currency | Side | Quote | Broker | 
|---------|----------|------|-------|--------|
|Acc1     |EUR/USD   |BUY   |1.218  |Brk3    |
|Acc1     |EUR/USD   |BUY   |1.216  |Brk6    |
|Acc2     |GBP/USD   |SELL  |1.345  |Brk6    |
|Acc2     |GBP/USD   |SELL  |1.330  |Brk5    |
|Acc2     |GBP/USD   |SELL  |1.341  |Brk3    |
```

It is important to note, that the columns which are to be transposed (Quote1, Broker1, Quote2, Broker2, Quote3, Broker3), should be transposed only if they do not contain NaNs.

I am fairly new to pandas so a tried a bit with multi indexes and pivots using other threads I found here, but I kept failing at the point where empty cells (like Quote3 and Broker3 of line 1 in dataframe 1) are to be ignored. It would be great, if you guys could help!

Cheers

PeterLustig20

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Great first question and good example of how to ask well formed pandas question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, ['Quote', 'Broker'],
                ['Account', 'Currency', 'Side'], 'j', suffix=r'\d+')\
  .dropna(how='all').droplevel(-1).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
  Account Currency  Side  Quote Broker
0    Acc1  EUR/USD   BUY  1.218   Brk3
1    Acc1  EUR/USD   BUY  1.216   Brk6
2    Acc2  GBP/USD  SELL  1.345   Brk6
3    Acc2  GBP/USD  SELL  1.330   Brk5
4    Acc2  GBP/USD  SELL  1.341   Brk3
```